# $L^p$ inequalities

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I just wonder if someone might give a hint. I've thought to apply Minkowski inequality, but I couldn't find out the way.

Given $2 \leq p<\infty$. Show that for any real-valued functions $f,g \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$, the following holds:
\begin{align*}
2 \left( \left\|\frac{f}{2} \right\|_{L^p}^p+  \left\|\frac{g}{2} \right\|_{L^p}^p\right)\leq  \left\|\frac{f-g}{2} \right\|_{L^p}^p+ \left\|\frac{f+g}{2} \right\|_{L^p}^p\leq \frac{1}{2}\left(\|f\|_{L^p}^p+\|g\|_{L^p}^p \right).
\end{align*}

*Proof:* For the  right hand side I realized the following:
\begin{align*}
  \left\|\frac{f-g}{2} \right\|_{L^p}^p+ \left\|\frac{f+g}{2} \right\|_{L^p}^p &\leq   \frac{1}{2^p}(\|f\|_{L^p}^p+\|g\|_{L^p}^p+\|f\|_{L^p}^p+\|g\|_{L^p}^p ) \quad \textrm{ by Minkowski inequality} \\
  &=\frac{1}{2^{p-1}}(\|f\|_{L^p}^p+\|g\|_{L^p}^p) \leq \frac{1}{2}(\|f\|_{L^p}^p+\|g\|_{L^p}^p).
\end{align*}
For the left  hand side,  we can observe that
$$
f=\frac{f+g}{2}+\frac{f-g}{2}  \quad \textrm{ and } \quad g=\frac{g+f}{2}-\frac{f-g}{2}. 
$$
Hence, 
\begin{align*}
 \left\|\frac{\frac{f+g}{2}+\frac{f-g}{2}}{2} \right\|_{L^p}^p+  \left\|\frac{\frac{f+g}{2}-\frac{f-g}{2}}{2} \right\|_{L^p}^p&\leq \frac{2}{2^p}\left( \left\|\frac{f-g}{2} \right\|_{L^p}^p+ \left\|\frac{f+g}{2} \right\|_{L^p}^p \right) \quad \textrm{by Minkowski inequality} \\ 
 & \leq \frac{1}{2}\left( \left\|\frac{f-g}{2} \right\|_{L^p}^p+ \left\|\frac{f+g}{2} \right\|_{L^p}^p\right)
\end{align*}
which is equivalent to 
$$
2 \left( \left\|\frac{f}{2} \right\|_{L^p}^p+  \left\|\frac{g}{2} \right\|_{L^p}^p\right)\leq  \left\|\frac{f-g}{2} \right\|_{L^p}^p+ \left\|\frac{f+g}{2} \right\|_{L^p}^p.
$$

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is apply the right-hand side that you successfully proved to $F=\frac{f+g}2$ and $G=\frac{f-g}2$.

Comment: You're accurate. Thanks so much!